# In gatling is it possible to execute conditional scenario

Tags: gatling

Imagine that we want to simulate that 10% of the connected users try to logout from a web site. How can i model this in gatling? I tried to use doIf with a variable it seems not to be the good way.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [randomSwitch](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#randomswitch) to apply weights on scenario branches.